# Is there join number limitation in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, join

I'm curious about what's the performance change if adding more joins? is there join number limitation? e.g. if greater than a value, the performance will be degraded. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maximum Number Of Tables In A Join**

SQLite does not support joins containing more than 64 tables. This limit arises from the fact that the SQLite code generator uses bitmaps with one bit per join-table in the query optimizer.

SQLite uses a very efficient O(N²) greedy algorithm for determining the order of tables in a join and so a large join can be prepared quickly. Hence, there is no mechanism to raise or lower the limit on the number of tables in a join.

see :http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html